# Parse in Python ASCII extended Characters located at the beginning

Tags: regex, python-2.7, robotframework, extended-ascii

I need to remove the first 3 or 4 ASCII extended chracters from a debug sentences in Python but I can't by now. This is an example:

`ª!è[002:58:535]REGMICRO:Load: 36.6`

`ëª7è[001:40:971]HTTP_CLI:Http Client Mng not initialized.`

I tried: 
`^.*[A-Za-z]+$`

and

`[\x80-\xFF]+HTTP_CLI:0 - Line written in.*`

But everything is ignored and gives me this error:

"`20160922 15:16:28.549 :  FAIL : UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x80' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
20160922 15:16:28.551 :  INFO : ${resulters} = ('FAIL', u"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\\x80' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)")
20160922 15:16:28.553 :  INFO : ('FAIL', u"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\\x80' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)")`"

Anyone who works on RIDE and Python?

Thank you!

Comment: are you saying the problem is with RIDE (the IDE), or a robot framework test? Those are two different things.

Comment: sorry the problem is with RIDE, running on Python, so I only want to ignore the first 3 or 4 chracters with a REGEX, that's it, but I can't find how...

Comment: So, you only get this problem when editing a test case, and doesn't happen when running a test case?

Comment: Is happening always, the problem is located in a log trace, so I need to "clean" the traces of this ASCII wear characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering how to remove the characters before the square brackets with RF (if I understood the question correctly, frankly - I'm not sure) - the regex you tried with is not correct; say you want to get everything after the first square bracket:

```
${line}=    Set Variable    ëª7è[001:40:971]HTTP_CLI:Http Client Mng not initialized.
${regx}=    Set Variable    ^.*(\\[.*$)
${result}=  Get Regexp Matches      ${line}      ${regx}      1
```

The regex you're going after (line 2 ^) is "from start of the line, skip everything up to the 1st square bracket - and the sequence from the square bracket to the end is group 1". Then using the kw "Get Regexp Matches" you get the matched group 1.

In python:

```
import re
line = "ëª7è[001:40:971]HTTP_CLI:Http Client Mng not initialized."
regx = "^.*(\\[.*$)"
result = re.search(regx, line).group(1)  # the value of result is "[001:40:971]HTTP_CLI:Http Client Mng not initialized."
```